# Get Powershell XML output to match SSMS FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS output

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that outputs 3 XML files from 3 queries.  Running the queries in SSMS with the `FOR XMl AUTO, ELEMENTS` statement gives me a nice XML file formatted just like I want.

But I need to make these queries run every hour so I made a PowerShell script and for the most part it works, but the way it puts the data is not really correct.  When viewing the XML it starts off with:

```
<Objs xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04" Version="1.1.0.1">
<Obj RefId="0">
<TN RefId="0">
<T>System.Data.DataRow</T>
<T>System.Object</T>
</TN>
<ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
```

Then has a  and then the data with each column it's own line then ending with a  and then starting back up with a new .  The column names are there but they are not in <> like they are in SSMS.  For example, instead of , it's Johnson and it will do that <S N=> thing for a few other columns then switch it up to <I32 N=> for a couple and also <DT N=>

Is there something I need to add to my PowerShell to get it to match what I see when running it in SSMS?  I have tried adding the `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS` back to my saved queries and running the PS script, but then I get almost the same outcome except all the data is ran together instead of on it's own line.

Script is below:

```
# Define SQL Server connection parameters
 $server = "xxx"
 $database = "xxx"
 $username = "xxx"
 $password = "xxx"

 # Define the directory containing SQL query files
 $queryDirectory = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Interface"

 # Define the directory to save the result XML files
 $resultDirectory = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Results"

 # Generate timestamp for the file name
 $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"

 # Define function to execute SQL query and export results to XML
 function Execute-SqlQueryAndExportToXml {
     param (
         [string] $queryFileName,
         [string] $resultFileName
     )

     $queryFile = Join-Path -Path $queryDirectory -ChildPath $queryFileName
     $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $resultDirectory -ChildPath "$resultFileName.xml"

     Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Username $username -Password $password -trustservercertificate  -InputFile $queryFile  |
     Export-clixml -Path $outputFile
 }

 # Execute each SQL query and export results to XML
 Execute-SqlQueryAndExportToXml -queryFileName "booking.sql" -resultFileName "booking_$timestamp"
 Execute-SqlQueryAndExportToXml -queryFileName "release.sql" -resultFileName "release_$timestamp"
 Execute-SqlQueryAndExportToXml -queryFileName "incident.sql" -resultFileName "incident_$timestamp"
```

Trying to get it to look like this (example)

```
<jinames>
  <book_id>xxxx</book_id>
  <name_id>xxxx</name_id>
  <jimain>
    <location>xxxx</location>
    <Type>xxx</Type>
    <incdate>xxx-xxx-xxx:xx:xxx</incdate>
    <inctime>xxxx</inctime>
    <jimainid>xxx</jimainid>
    <locationcd>xxx</locationcd>
    <jidisc>
      <dispositn>xxx</dispositn>
      <jiviol>
        <violcode>xxxx</violcode>
        <violdesc>xxxxxxxxxx</violdesc>
      </jiviol>
    </jidisc>
  </jimain>
</jinames>
```

Comment: Use `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS` in the query, and then _skip `Export-CliXml` completely_ - it's designed specifically to serialize PowerShell ETS objects, not for creating arbitrary xml files. If the sql query returns the document as a single string, simply cast it to `[xml]` and save the resulting document (or write it directly to disk)

Answer (score 1):

`FOR XML` queries stream to the client across multiple rows of a single-column resultset.  So you just need to iterate the results and append the first column to a file.  Something like:

```
$server = "localhost"
$database = "tempdb"
$query = "select * from sys.objects for xml auto, elements, root"
$file = "c:\temp\out.xml"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database  -Query $query

set-content $file ""
foreach ($row in $results)
{
    Add-Content -NoNewline -Path $file -Value $row[0]
}

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($file)
write-host $doc.ToString()
```

You can also return the XML as a single string by writing a query that returns an XML type in a single column, like this:

```
$sql = "select (select * from sys.objects for xml auto, elements, type, root) doc"
$xml = (invoke-sqlcmd -server localhost -database tempdb -MaxCharLength -1 -query $sql)[0]
$xml
```

Comment: I think one can wrap the xml code in a subquery to get one long xml string

Comment: Good point.  Added that to the answer.

Comment: So if I had 3 queries I wanted ran, I would need to make 3 powershell batch files instead of the one I was trying to make that called in the saved .sql files?

Comment: You can run queries stored in files like you were.  It's just a simpler and more generally applicable to leave that stuff out of my answer.  Similarly I think it would be better practice for your powershell function to accept a SQL string instead of a file name.  Then if you want to use a file, read the SQL from the file before you call the function.  That way your function follows the "single responsibility principle". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: So I downloaded the adventureworks database to test this on, and got that code you reccomended in, but I get the following errors:Line |
  35 |  $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($file)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 343."
InvalidOperation:
Line |
  36 |  write-host $doc.ToString()
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: SQL XML returns XML fragments by default.  If you want a an XML document with a root element, you need to ask for one like in my queries above.  Also make sure you're not appending multiple documents to the same file when running your code multiple times.

Comment: cool, actually I found a mistake I had made that I think was giving that error.  I corrected the mistake and not I think the XML document looks like how I want it, at least using the adventureworks test.  Tommorow I will try it with my actual database and see what happens.  One weird thing though is that the timestamp I am putting in the generated file is now off by like a day and few hours.